# GeoServer remove background color

Tags: geoserver

I have single band DEMs I'm trying to use in an ImageMosaic in GeoServer 2.11.2 that displays a black background color by default. I want that background color to go away and the default color ramping to range of displayed values to occur.

[image]

The default behavior is almost exactly what I want - when you zoom in, it scales the colors to the min/max of the dataset currently in view.

[image]

All I want to do is hide the background color of -9999.0 so that scaling isn't messed up by the nodata color. However all attempts to fix this don't seem to work.

-Setting InputTransparentColor and OutputTransparentColor cause rendering to fail with an error 'Unsupported data type'.

-Setting an SLD ColorMap that hides -9999.0 values 'works' but you need to then to specify the rest of the color ramp which I don't want to do because it needs to be dynamic. (So I don't want [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190947/changing-background-color-to-transparent-in-geoserver) answer).

-Setting an SLD ContrastEnhancement causes a NullPointerException

```
<ContrastEnhancement>
  <Normalize />
</ContrastEnhancement>
```

And trying to set VendorOptions inside the ContrastEnhancement Node doesn't validate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aerial imagery showing in different colour while pan/zoom GeoServer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112817/aerial-imagery-showing-in-different-colour-while-pan-zoom-geoserver)

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, but we're both dealing with the ImageMosaic plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed this sentence `The default behavior is almost exactly what I want - when you zoom in, it scales the colors to the min/max of the dataset currently in view.`.

Comment: Do you use [JAI-EXT](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/image_processing/index.html#jai-ext) extension? Normal JAI can not handle nodata value.

Comment: I don't, but should! Thanks I didn't know about jai-ext before. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem...but I'm new to jai-ext obviously so do you have a configuration that might work differently or should it work out of the box? But, the behavior I want _does_ exist using a single mosaicked image (loaded without imagemosaic) without any tweaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input/output transparency colors do not work with floating point image mosaics.

The easiest way is probably to add a transparency mask to each of the image, this can be done with GDAL -

```
gdalwarp -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -srcnondata -9999 -dstnodata -9999 -dstalpha <input image> <output image>
```

The other options involve creating footprints file or files for the granules in the mosaic, and configuring the behavior of the footprints. See [GeoServer Documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_footprint/imagemosaic_footprint.html).

Creating the ShapeFile with the actual image footprints can be done with a combination of GDAL tools:

Create a virtual coverage with of the nodata area -

`gdal_translate -b mask -of vrt -a_nodata 0  <image file> <image>.vrt`

Use polygonize to create polygons that represent the data & nodata regions of the image
`gdal_polygonize.py -b 1 -8 -q -f gml <image>.vrt <image>.gml footprint DN`

Use ogr2ogr to add the data to a shapefile

`ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dialect SQLite -append -sql "select ST_BuildArea(ST_ExteriorRing(geometryProperty)),'<image file>' as location from footprint where DN=255" footprints.shp <image>.gml`

Answer (score -1):

try using EQCL filtering in Coverage Parameters (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html#coverage-parameters)

Comment: ECQL filtering does not filter raster values but removes granules dependent on attributes in the index table.